# Can PhoneGap send headers

Tags: uiwebview, cordova

Can I have PhoneGap send a header for http requests coming from its UIWebView (or the Android equivalent)? I would like to tell when a user is browsing my site through my app without the need for an entrance point and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understand you question... However.

Yes. You can use an ajax library or write a vanilla XHR request in your Phonegap app. When you execute the request a header is generated and sent to wherever you direct it.

Comment: I meant during normal browsing, not using ajax. I would like to have it send a custom header, like X-MyApp, primarily to tell that they're browsing through the app (and perhaps give a link to return to the app).